# is there way to bind datatable in MVC like binding datasource to grid in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I'm new to asp.net MVC, I want to bind datatable to grid like binding datasource to gridview in asp.net without models and mentioning columns as the datatable in generated at the runtime. Help me out guys.

Comment: MVC usually use class to bind the data. You need research in collection e.g. List<Class>, array, collection and etc. Besides, you can use Entity Framework to bind the data to the collection class. It is much easier than data table. Do some research, I suggest you to go to Microsoft website and look at the beginner tutorial.

Comment: In other words the posters can't help much, and you have to go learn BOATLOADS of work and do all kinds of circus hand stands to do what is trivial in webforms? Is that what you saying @YatFeiLeong ? In other words, boatloads of extra work and learning, and no one here can post a simple example? Ok, that makes perfect sense and we all thank you for your great help here. So, you mean in MVC we can't send a simple query to a grid control??? So all this extra effort is for what, to create world poverty?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application Follow this, there are plenty of resources online. Even when someone tries to help you, there must be some way to start from, right?

Comment: You will have to create html table on view then you have to pass data to the view as a model. You can use Viewbag to send this data. Then on the view you make this html table dynamic by looping through this viewbag variable and creating the html table in runtime. There are lots of tutorials on this, you just need to google them.